# PHP white screen of death fix

Tags: php

White screen of death happens when the interpreter finds a fatal error and its not configured to output errors.
How to debug a PHP white screen of death without touching the config.ini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to register an hook to make the last error or warning visible.

```
function shutdown(){
  var_dump(error_get_last());
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

adding this code to the beginning of you index.php will help you debug the problems.